# How do I load all fields from a database and sort the result after one row with GreenDao?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, greendao

I want to load all entities from a sqlite database with greendao and sort the result.

I can load all entities with [loadAll](http://greendao-orm.com/javadoc/greendao/index.html?de/greenrobot/dao/AbstractDao.html) but this doesn't gives me a guarantee about the sorting of the resulting list.

Comment: `AbstractDao.queryBuilder().orderAsc(...).list()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `queryBiulder` like below:

```
List joes = userDao.queryBuilder().where(Properties.FirstName.eq("Joe")).orderAsc(Properties.LastName).list();
```

for all rows:

```
List joes = userDao.queryBuilder().orderAsc(Properties.LastName).list();
```

[Source](http://greendao-orm.com/javadoc/greendao/de/greenrobot/dao/QueryBuilder.html)

Comment: That loads only the row where username is Joe. I want to load all fields of the table.

Comment: This is an example you can change the query to load all.

Comment: And how do I do that?